# javscript that updates div in a single wordpress page

Tags: javascript

I would like to execute the following code in a single wordpress page. I do not want to change the template. How to do it - the problem is with "div" that does not exist in the template. Thank you.

```
<div id="calendar_embed"></div><script>(function(){fetch("https://url").then(response => response.text()).then(data => {document.getElementById("calendar_embed").innerHTML = data;});})();</script>
```

Comment: If the desired `<div>` isn't in the template file, you'll need to add it somehow. You might need to edit the template file, or you might be able to write a filter for [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) that will add the `<div>` on the specific page(s) where you need it.